# Removing indexes from fulltext search

Tags: java, google-app-engine

It is possible to remove documents from index, but is it possible to remove whole index programmatically? (I searched the IP and couldn't find anything).

Also, in the management console, you can only see the indexes, but there is not an option to remove index even if index contains no documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, while currently you can remove all the documents from an index, you can't delete the index. (This will be possible in future).